# How do I completely close an app during an Espresso test

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm using activityScenario rule like this:

```
    @Rule
    @JvmField
    var activityScenarioRule: ActivityScenarioRule<MainActivity> = ActivityScenarioRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity::class.java)
```

To close app I've tried:

```
 activityScenarioRule.scenario.moveToState( Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED)
```

I've also tried

```
activityScenarioRule.scenario.close()
```

However I can still see the app when I click "Recent apps" button. It seems to be just backgrounded. I need to close the app completely because when I open the app for the second test it needs to start again.

I also tried modifying the manifest:

```
<activity  android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you [enable Android Test Orchestrator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner#using-android-test-orchestrator), then every test method will be run in a separate process.